# A good wxpython GUI builder?

Tags: python, wxpython, gui-builder

Is there a good wxpython GUI builder that does not require much coding, like in the case of the form builder in MS visual studio ?

Comment: I recommend going at it by hand. It's really not hard at all.

Comment: I agree with Bryan. I hand-code almost every wxPython program I write.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/). Here is a screenshot:

[image]

and [wxFormBuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/)

[image]

Also, have a look here for more alternatives: [GUI Programming in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming)

Answer (score 8):

I've tried a few, and the only one I seem to have any luck with is [wxFormBuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to those, some people really like the XRCed application that's included with wxPython. Basically you create your GUI in XML. There's also the defunct Boa Constructor that I see people still using on the wxPython user's list.

Answer (score 3):

In a long ago day, I tried them all and found [Anthemion DialogBlocks](http://www.dialogblocks.com/) to be the most professional of the bunch.  Along with that goes the fact that it is commercial software.

It's by Julian Smart, the creator of wxWidgets, so I suppose it's not too surprising that it's a quality product.  At $90, it's a bit expensive but not outrageous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ezWxPython. it is not gui builder, but it helps you make layout easy same way as pySimpleGUI.