# GUI builder for wxWidgets wxPython

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

The best drag and drop GUI builder for wxPython? 
I've tried wxGlade but its not drag and drop, found it difficult to understand, you have to work with sizers.
I would prefer an application which is fully drop and drag like VisualTinker but for wxpython

Any suggestions guys/girls?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A good wxpython GUI builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079866/a-good-wxpython-gui-builder)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wxFormBuilder, DialogBlocks, and the XRCed utility that comes with wxPython sort of has this.

By the way, this question may be a dupe of [A good wxpython GUI builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079866/a-good-wxpython-gui-builder)